# How to run multiple instance of same program in java

Tags: java, multithreading, javacv

I am doing my final Year project on Speed Calculation using webcam. In this project we want to calculate speed of object by taking three sequential images whenever motion is detected. As given here: [Raser Abwehr SpeedCam 2012](http://www.raserabwehr.de/), in this three line `RED` `BLUE` and `GREEN` are made and whenever any vehicle cross it, it takes one snap.

For this I have idea that suppose my camera resolution is `640*480` hence I can divide X-Axis in three parts of `210px` each therefore I can have three rectangular screens of size `(210*480)`. Now, I want that whenever any vehicle enters in `Screen1` then it click a picture then it start second screen detector and when vehicle enters into second screen it takes second picture and at last it detect in third and click picture. Hence we have three picture and we can calculate Speed by process given here [Calculating Speed using a Webcam](http://morefunscience.blogspot.com/2012/05/calculating-speed-using-webcam.html)

Presently, I am using [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) as Image Processing Library. It is just like running multiple instance of a single Java program to detect motion in different screen. Please suggest to me how i can do. Can `Thread` be useful here?

Comment: I am Using JAVACV as Image Processing Library.

Comment: It is Just Like Running Multiple Instance of a single JAVA program to detect motion in different screen.please suggest me the method by which i can do.is Thread can be useful here????

Comment: Yes, threading will be much more helpful to your program than just running multiple instances.  Additionally, please don't post comments as edits to your questions, just edit the question with the additional information.  The comments section is for replying to users that have comments on your question.

Comment: But why do you want to run multiple instances of same program? I think reading from webcam will be a bottle neck here. You can run it in single thread (or program as you call it) and organize your logic to divide your screen into 3 pieces and save 3 different pictures.

Answer (score 0):

(More like a comment but it doesn't fit)
I'd suggest by starting try making it work by taking three pictures at a fixed interval (which you guess).

Then, if you want to address the issue of detecting speed of objects that are moving at quite different speeds, I'd just suggest by starting with taking as many pictures as possible once you detect any movement, for a sufficiently long time, and then figuring out afterwards which one you should use for the analysis.

I can see what you are trying to do but you should probably start with dumb things first. Just my two cents...